# Python 3 chess engine draws pieces in wrong places

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, chess

I am trying to create a chess game but it has a weird bug and I cannot see where it comes from. I can move pieces by selecting the piece and then selecting an empty square. But if I select any of the squares in the four middle rows, the game creates pieces in each row in the column that I selected.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import os
import pygame

class Board:
    def __init__(self, window, width, height):
        self.window = window
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.w = self.width/8
        self.h = self.height/8

    def draw_board(self):
        """
        Draw the squares on the board.
        """
        cornsilk = (255, 248, 220)
        brown = (160, 82, 45)
        count = 0
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                square = pygame.Rect(i*self.w, j*self.h, self.w, self.h) # x, y, w, h
                if count % 2 == 0:
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.window, cornsilk, square)
                else:
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.window, brown, square)
                count += 1
            count -= 1

    def initial_board_occupation(self):
        """
        Create initial board occupation.
        """
        black_other = ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"]
        black_pawns = ["bp" for i in range(8)]
        white_other = ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]
        white_pawns = ["wp" for i in range(8)]
        empty_row = ["--" for i in range(8)]
        board = [black_other, black_pawns, empty_row, empty_row,
                 empty_row, empty_row, white_pawns, white_other]
        return board

    def load_images(self):
        """
        Load images for pieces.
        """
        white_other = ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]
        black_other = ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"]
        pawns = ["bp", "wp"]
        pieces = white_other + black_other + pawns
        images = {}
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        image_directory = os.path.join(cwd, "images")
        for piece in pieces:
            image_path = os.path.join(image_directory, piece)
            image_file = "{}.png".format(image_path)
            image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
            images[piece] = pygame.transform.scale(image, (self.w, self.h))
        return images

    def draw_pieces(self, board, images):
        """
        Draw pieces on the board.
        """
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                piece = board[row][col]
                if piece != "--":
                    rect = pygame.Rect(col*self.w, row*self.h, self.w, self.h)
                    self.window.blit(images[piece], rect)

    def draw_game_state(self, board_occupation):
        """
        Draw current game state.
        """
        self.draw_board()
        images = self.load_images()
        self.draw_pieces(board_occupation, images)

class Move:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start_row = int(start[0])
        self.start_col = int(start[1])
        self.end_row = int(end[0])
        self.end_col = int(end[1])
        self.move_log = []

    
    def make_move(self, board):
        start = board[self.start_row][self.start_col]
        new_board = board
        new_board[self.start_row][self.start_col] = "--"
        new_board[self.end_row][self.end_col] = start
        return new_board

class Main:
    def __init__(self, window, width, height, fps):
        self.window = window
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps
        self.w = self.width/8
        self.h = self.height/8
    
    def board(self):
        """
        Draw board and pieces.
        """
        B = Board(self.window, self.width, self.height)
        init_board = B.initial_board_occupation()
        B.draw_game_state(init_board)
        return B, init_board

    def run(self):
        """
        Run the game.
        """
        pygame.init()
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Chess AI")
        B, board = self.board()
        pygame.display.update()
        running = True
        selected_location = ()
        player_clicks = []
        while running:
            clock.tick(self.fps)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    location = pygame.mouse.get_pos() # (x, y) location of mouse
                    row = int(location[1]//self.h)
                    col = int(location[0]//self.w)
                    if selected_location == (row, col):
                        selected_location = ()
                        player_clicks = []
                    else:
                        selected_location = (row, col)
                        player_clicks.append(selected_location)
                        if len(player_clicks) == 2:
                            start = player_clicks[0]
                            end = player_clicks[1]
                            if board[start[0]][start[1]] != "--":
                                MO = Move(start, end)
                                new_board = MO.make_move(board)
                                B.draw_game_state(board)
                                selected_location = ()
                                player_clicks = []
                                board = new_board
                            selected_location = ()
                            player_clicks = []
                
            pygame.display.update()                       
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    width, height = 600, 600
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    fps = 60
    M = Main(window, width, height, fps)
    M.run()
```

In order for the code to run, you have to download images from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qH7IQj5lj7o3MQIb5TAZhsDr_5f9p8aq) and place them in a directory called "images". This directory should be in the same directory as the code above.

Let's say I move black pawn from `(row, col) = (1, 0)` to `(2, 0)`, I expect the board to be as follows:

```
[['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'], 
['--', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'], 
['bp', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'], 
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'], 
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'], 
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'], 
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']]
```

But instead I get:

```
[['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'], 
['--', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'], 
['bp', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'], 
['bp', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'], 
['bp', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['bp', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'], 
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'], 
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']]
```

I have tried debugging this for a couple of days but nothing seems to work. When I make a move to the 4 middle rows and try to update the board, it always updates the same column from the 4 middle rows. I obviously want to update only the square that I have selected. Can anyone see where the problem is, I am not able to find it?